# Parse a group of JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have some json data in this format

```
    var dataJSON = '[["a","b","0","1"],["c","d","3","4"],["e","f","5","6"],["g","h","7","8"],["i","j","9","10"]]';
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=dataJSON;
```

and html:

```
<div id="description"></div>
```

Ho to target just the first value in each array, so the result can be "a - c - e - g - i"

*Edited

Comment: `JSON.parse( dataJSON ).map( arr => arr[0] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` with `map`:

```
const first = JSON.parse(dataJSON).map(([e]) => e);
```

To join that into a string separated by hyphens and spaces:

```
const str = first.join(" - ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse the string to json object and loop through the array and get the first element of the array element

```
var dataJSON = '[["a","b","0","1"],["c","d","3","4"],["e","f","5","6"],["g","h","7","8"],["i","j","9","10"]]';

var result = [];

JSON.parse(dataJSON).forEach(function(d){
  result.push(d[0]);
});

console.log(result.join(' - ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Code example.

```
var dataJSON = '[["a","b","0","1"],["c","d","3","4"],["e","f","5","6"],["g","h","7","8"],["i","j","9","10"]]';

console.log(JSON.parse(dataJSON).map(item => item[0]));

// ["a", "c", "e", "g", "i"]
```